# Request size limit on server and connection reset after attachment upload

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

What can we do about connection reset error that domino sends back to our application after submiting attachment which size exceeds limit of request size? We use standard upload control.

Is there anything that will allow us to handle this error? At this moment this is a very serious problem because it can lead to data loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your browser supports the html5 files API. When yes - checking the file size before upload is possible (there is an example on so somewhere). Other than that I second Ferry's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Xpage actualy, but i ve got a similar problem in domino 6. 
To correct this limit, i use a temporary document in a pop-up. The attachement is saved in the temporary document, and an agent copy the attachement from the temporary document to the final document when the user save is document.

Another agent delete temp documents each night.

I hope that will hep you.

Answer (score 0):

The upload limit could be set in Application Properties in the tab Xpages and there is a 'Maximum Post Data' setting on your website document on tab 'Domino Web Engine'.

I wrote a free async file upload control for Xpages, where you can prevent the user to upload too big files before the upload starts. You can download it [here](http://www.openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?databaseName=CN=NotesOSS2/O=NotesOSS!!Projects%5Cpmt.nsf&documentId=D5639B5FFB2823F8862578AF00705169&action=openDocument)